# Webdav Client on iOS caching

Tags: ios, webdav

I am working on a webdav client for iOS device, will NSURLConnection or ASIHTTPRequest help with caching directory listing of webdav, or will we have to load from the server everytime?

Thank for your help guys.

Comment: Not sure about webdav but ASIHTTPRequest does support proper caching mechanisms when it comes to plain HTTP (eg. ETAG Header Requests).

Answer (score 1):

[MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) is an up and coming network kit for iOS 4+ that has built in caching for requests.

Comment: Seems to be promising ASI-replacement (which I loved using in the past).

Comment: yeah looks promising, will this work for caching webdav stuff

Comment: MKNetworkKit supports ETag based caching. that means if your server sends changes the Etag (to denote content change), MKNetworkKit will re-download the content.